# Jquery AJAX Json Response data not showing up in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

The ajax request dataType must be sent as xml due to the fact that the API only xml. I am using a plugin script to allow me to bypass the cross domain issue. The script is found below.
The response is returned as json because of the plugin being used.

I have no idea why I cannot get the individual response data to show up. The only thing I've managed to get to display is [object object] in the browser.

https://github.com/denka/jQuery-Plugins/blob/e5f123741ce6bc1be93e1db846a0e59cfe7e750c/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

Any suggestions in order to get this working will be greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.smartpea.com/api/deal/?title=water&zip=90210, ///URL + User Input
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(){// Before Send, Add the Loader
    $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function(){// Once Request is complete, Remove the Loader
    $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function(data){
        var placement = document.getElementById('content');// location to where response is to be displayed to the user

        jQuery.parseJSON(data); parse the json response
        $.each(data, function(i) {

        placement.innerHTML = data[i].Title, data[i]. BrandName, data[i]. CurrentPrice, data[i].Category; //adding the response data to the content holder in the browser
        });     
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){// Error Logger
    console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
    }   

});
```

Comment: The `placement.innerHTML = ...` line is invalid - not sure what you're going for there, but your comma-separated values would give a javascript error.

Comment: I'm a newbie with Jquery and I wasn't sure how I could go about passing those items from the json response to my content div. I also tried appending them to it as well but that didn't work out either.

Comment: If your response is XML, and you're calling `parseJSON` on it, it'll definitely blow up.

Comment: If you're getting the `[object Object]`, then at least you've got something. Find out where that line is, and throw a breakpoint on it and explore the properties.

Comment: Don't mix `innerHTML`, `getElementById` with jQuery: take full advantage of it once you imported the library.

Comment: If you change the dataType to jsonp. It will act like it is working. The response information will come back correctly. When it finishes the request, you will get a parsererror in the console log. I'm beyond puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious error is the missing quotation mark at the end of the URL on the second line. You should consider using `JSHint` on your code.

Comment: Can you provide some reasons why the OP should consider using JSHint?

Comment: Aside from catching basic errors like the one in the example, it also helps enforce good JS style and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your sucess function may be like this

```
 success: function(data){
            jQuery.parseJSON(data); parse the json response
            $.each(data, function(i) {
            $('#content').html(data[i].Title+','+data[i]. BrandName+','+data[i]. CurrentPrice+','+data[i].Category)

            });     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.smartpea.com/api/deal/?title=water&zip=90210',
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(){
    $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function(data){
        var placement = document.getElementById('content');

        jQuery.parseJSON(data); parse the json response
        $.each(data, function(i) {
        placement.innerHTML = data[i].Title + " - " + data[i].BrandName + " - " + data[i].CurrentPrice + " - " + data[i].Category;
        });     
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: It seemed to work but the data items are showing up as undefined - undefined - undefined - undefined.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of my request result.

http://pastebin.com/FMHaUeVt

I'm still not sure to why everything shows up as undefined. The validation tool that I have been using is showing that the json returned is valid but it comes back with a lot of extra stuff in it.

jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com